# Responsive Full page background image

Tags: html, css

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/129673910/Sylhetcricket-5/index.html 
This my web site url link. When i try it to responsive then background image can not be responsive

Comment: Please invest some effort into asking a clear question, we will be able to better provide you with a meaningful answer.

Comment: Use background-size: cover; if you want to fill the window with the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/DrabA/1/

Don't give specific height - it won't be responsive otherwise.

```
body {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image:url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```